# Redirect output of remote python app started through ssh to file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, python, redirection

I have a python app in a remote server that i need to debug, when I run the app locally it prints some debug information (including python tracebacks) that i need to monitor.

Im trying to redirect all the output of the program to a file so I can monitor the remote output using *tail -F*, [here](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/working-with-python-subprocess.html) I found the following command to redirect the outputs:

```
ssh root@myserver 'nohup python /root/python/run_dev_server.py &>> /var/log/myapp.log &'
```

This gets me almost exactly what i want, loggin information and python tracebacks, but i do not get any of the information displayed using *print* from python, which i need.

so I also tried this command:

```
ssh root@myserver 'nohup python /root/python/run_dev_server.py 2>&1 >> /var/log/myapp.log &'
```

this logs the output of the program from *print* and also the logging information, but all the tracebacks are sent to my local terminal where i excecuted the the script and my script gets stuck waiting for any exception to happen in the remote program.

Is there a way I can capture all the information produced by the app without stopping my script?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it... However, all three pipes need to be re-directed to background a process via ssh.  Std In, Std Out, Std Err.  Thus:

```
nohup /root/python/run_dev_server.py &>/var/log/my.app.log </dev/null &
```

note:  &> is the equivalent of redirecting std out and std error at the same time. In other words, it is the shortened version of ' >> /var/log/myapp.log 2>&1'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ ssh  -t root@192.168.113.67 "tail -f /var/log/messages" | tee -a mss.txt
```